# Combinatorial optimization algorithm with constraints and objective function

Tags: combinatorics, linear-programming, knapsack-problems, integer-programming

I'm looking for an algorithm that will let me optimally select items from a set. These items have properties which are involved in defining constraints as well as the objective function.

.e.g
Say each item in the set has integer-valued properties `A, B, C`. I need to select `n` items (say 2, can pick any item at most once) such that the sum of the property B among all selected items is at least 50 and the sum of all C's is at least 60 (two constraints), and I need to maximize for sum of A.

Where should I start looking? I was pointed towards LP but am unable to formulate it since I'm looking to pick exact items from a set.

Comment: Do you mean LP (linear programming) or ILP (integer linear programming)?

Comment: @D.W. I'm not fully aware of the differences, but this is what I looked at: https://developers.google.com/optimization/lp/glop#stigler

Comment: ILP is a LP where the variables are restricted to take integer values. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Integer_unknowns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed formulate an Integer Linear Program. Let $x_i \in \{0,1\}$ denote whether you select item $i$. For each item $i$ define $f_a(i)$,  $f_b(i)$, and $f_c(i)$ as the integer values for the properties $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Then we define the objective function as maximizing $\sum_{i = 1}^{m} f_a(i) \cdot x_i$, given $m$ items in total.

Your constraints are very similar as well, namely $\sum_{i = 1}^{m} f_b(i) \cdot x_i \geq 50$, and $\sum_{i = 1}^{m} f_c(i) \cdot x_i \geq 60$.

Since you can select at most $n$ of those $m$ items, you need to following constraint: $\sum_{i = 1}^{m} x_i \leq n$.

You can then easily recover the solution from your variables. Simply check whether $x_i = 1$, and if so, add item $i$ to your solution.

Comment: Thank you, this helped